# How to get Exact file location selected from <input type="file"> tag

Tags: jquery

I have a File tag in my JSP and when I select file I get

```
c:/fakepath/document.xlsx
```

but I need

```
D:/doc/document.xlsx
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#file').on('change', function() {
        var filePath = $(this).val();
        $('#filePath').val(filePath);
        console.log($('#filePath').val())
    });
});
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is big **NO**. You can't and don't do that.

Why?

> Because almost all modern  Browsers have a security feature that prevents JavaScript to
>   know your file's full path. It's good security feature. As a client
>   (end user), people don't want Server know their PC file system.